# How to give the recusive option (-R) to the M command (change the file mod) in emacs dired?

Tags: emacs, dired

When i type "-R 777" I get:
file-modes-symbolic-to-number: Parse error in modes near `R 777'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive operations aren't supported by `dired-do-chmod`.

It's easy to do this as a shell command, though:
<kbd>M-!</kbd> `chmod -R 777 (files)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Alternatively, the [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired%2B.el) library provides a `diredp-do-chmod-recursive` command for this, bound to <kbd>M-+</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> (and added only a few days ago, apparently, so that was a well-timed question).